# How to add multiplicity for formatting data?

Tags: python, format

I am writing data to a text file as follows but I need a simple way to add a multiple arguments in a single line rather than typing for example, {14.4f} like 20 times. Is there some feature as 20*{14.4f} I could use? I have tried several approaches but they do not work.

```
   filename='/home/text/test.txt'
   f = open(filename, "w") #open text file for writing results
   f.write('{:5d} {:4d} {:4d} {:4d} {:14.4f} {:14.4f}'.format(2019, 249, 11,37, 1150.48898852, 1120.454545454545))
   f.write('\n')
   f.close()
```

Comment: `('{:5d} {:4d} {:4d} {:4d}' + 20 * '  {:14.4f}').format(...)` ^^

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, just updated above. It worked.